# phpMyAdmin choosing wrong db when following link

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, linux-mint

For a personal admin page on my local machine I am going to use phpMyAdmin to amend records. The link in my menu I use is this:

```
echo "<li><a href='http://localhost/phpmyadmin/sql.php?server=1&db=a4&table=b4_players&pos=0/'>Amend Player</a></li>";
```

This works fine if I am logged in to phpMyAdmin, if I'm not it takes me to the login page, I enter my credentials and it gives me the following error:-

> **#1146** - Table 'civ.b4_players' doesn't exist

Well no it doesn't - that table is in a4 which is the value in the URL but here's the page logging in takes you to:-

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin/index.php?db=a4&table=b4_players&target=sql.php&token=a09689275bd277944eac63ea20a0f1x7#PMAURL-0:index.php?db=civ&table=b4_players&server=1&target=sql.php&token=a09689275bd277944eac63ea20a0f1x7
```

As you can see the first half of the url is correct and contains `db=a4` but the second now says `db=civ`!

I thought perhaps there was some weird default db thing happening but can't see any setting for this, and it shouldn't override a specific instruction anyway.

In case it matter here is my setup.

> Linuz Mint 17.1 xfce
>
> 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> **PHP Version:** 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11
>
> **MySQL Server version:** 5.5.44-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
>
> **phpMyAdmin Version:** 4.0.10deb1

Same results on both *Chrome* and *Firefox*.

Comment: PHP is entirely server side.  Your browser wouldn't matter.  What's your connection string look like?  Are you sure you're pointing at the correct database?

Comment: Not sure at all but can you clear cookies and check results?

Comment: I know the browser shouldn't matter but always good practice to check :-)

Clearing cache makes no difference.

I'm definitely connected to the right db - the page on which the link is is displaying data from a4.